# using % in IN operator of sql

Tags: sql

I have a query like this

```
select * from table_employee where name in ('Jack','Jon','Jade');
```

and it gives me three results.
but I want to use % with the names I mentioned in query like:

```
select * from table_employee where name in ('%Jack%','%Jon%','%Jade%');
```

The query execution is completed but now I get no results. Whats wrong here and how can i use % in IN operator?

Comment: You can not use wildcards in `IN`. Only in `LIKE`

Comment: but then what's the solution here?

Comment: `where Name like '%J%'`? maybe. We not know what you need excactly you do not give us enough informations

Comment: What database are you using?  Why didn't you tell us that you have thousands of names?

Comment: Create a table with all the names to look for, do a join, and do a LIKE between the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_employee
WHERE NAME LIKE '%Jack%'
    OR NAME LIKE '%Jon%'
    OR NAME LIKE '%Jade%';
```

Comment: *Convert it to an OR*  Why?

Comment: can't do it as have thousands of names

Comment: It will do the same thing as the IN operator, but in this case you will be able to use wildcards..only sometimes, depending on the situation, you could get performance issues using `OR` instead of `IN`, but in this case it should just be fine.

Comment: Ah, your query seemed pretty static. Then you can create this query dynamically and then execute it at once. Do you have the thousands of names saved somewhere on a database table?

Answer (score 1):

You should use LIKE combined with OR, IN does not support wildcards

```
select * from table_employee where name LIKE '%Jack%'
OR name LIKE '%Jon%';
```

Answer (score 1):

The in keyword does not work like that. You can use a like operand and bind the three values with or
example

```
SELECT *
FROM table_employee
WHERE NAME LIKE '%Jack%'
    OR NAME LIKE '%Jon%'
    OR NAME LIKE '%Jade%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fields data are exact what you want get in the result is no needed to use **like** . You should use like only when you don't know the data in a field but you know that it could contains a string **Jack** for example .

I'm sayng this because if you have an index on the field where you use **LIKE** it will be not used , so you will get performance problem .